# Prove a specific function is linear

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have $$V^* = \{h: V \rightarrow R: h \text{ is linear} \}$$

For each element in the basis of $V$, I have a function $f$ that takes in a basis vector, and returns 1 if it's that vector, otherwise 0. For example if $\vec{b_i}$ and $\vec{b_j}$ are in the basis of $V$, define $f_i: V \rightarrow \{0, 1\}$, where $f_i(\vec{b_i}) = 1$ and $f_i(\vec{b_j}) = 0$. I'm showing that $f$ is in $V^*$ ($f$ is linear).

I would like to prove that $f$ is linear, but I'm struggling because let's take $\vec{\alpha} = c_1\vec{b_i} + c_2\vec{b_j}$, then $f_i(\vec{\alpha}) = 0$, but $c1*f_i(\vec{b_i}) + c2*f_i(\vec{b_j}) = c_1 + 0 = c_1$, so $f_i(\vec{\alpha}) \neq c1*f_i(\vec{b_i}) + c2*f_i(\vec{b_j})$.

I would really appreciate any help

Comment: $c_1\cdot f_i(b_i)=c_1$ not 1

Comment: Sorry my bad, I'm editing it now.

Comment: It's not clear how you determined that $f_i(\alpha)=0$.

Comment: It's because $f_i$ is only 1 for $\vec{b_i}$ and 0 for all others vectors in V

Comment: I think something is wrong with your assumptions. Because following suit, $f(2b_i)$ would then also be zero.

Comment: I think $f$ is being defined on a basis, and **extended** to the whole space in such a way that it's linear. There is always a unique way of doing this. So, the original $f$ on the basis is not linear (it can't be; it must be defined on a whole vector space), and the extended $f$ is linear basically by definition.